# Cast varchar to boolean

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to "copy" values from a varchar field to a boolean field. In the varchar field I have values like "yes" and "no". When I want to feed my boolean field I have an error message indicate me that I need to do a type transformation. I need a cast I think but I don't know how to write it.

An theoretical example

```
INSERT INTO mytable (booleanfield)
VALUES (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN varcharfield like 'yes' THEN 'true' 
        WHEN varcharfield like 'no' THEN 'false'
        END
        FROM mytable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change columns of existing rows, you need an UPDATE for this. INSERT is used to create completely new rows.

You can update the column like this:

```
update mytable
   set boolean_column = varchar_column = 'yes'
```

Note that this is slightly different than your CASE expression as it treats everything that is not `'yes'` as `false`. So the value `'foobar'` would also be treated as `false`

Online example: https://rextester.com/IJTW96016

Comment: All the values in the boolean field have a "true" value although I write a condition, how can I fix this ? `update mytable set booleanfield = varcharfield = 'yes' where varcharfield like 'yes'; `

Comment: Then apparently all rows contain the value `yes` in that column (Note that `like 'yes'` is the same as `= 'yes'` - the LIKE is useless without a wildcard)

Comment: Thanks for you're detail answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

[`varcharfield::boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-boolean.html)

to cast your string to boolean

such as

```
INSERT INTO mytable2(booleanfield,varcharfield)
SELECT varcharfield::boolean,varcharfield FROM mytable;
```

where mytable2 is created by

`CREATE TABLE mytable2 AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=0`

depending on the `insert` logic in the question. Or directly prefer using `update` as :

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET booleanfield=varcharfield::boolean;
```

> being 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'y' or 'Y' is converted to `true`,
>               'No' or 'no' or 'n' or 'N' is converted to `false`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5af3e2de48e6bbc0ea8c6db02154dcf3)</kbd>

Comment: I have an error message with this syntax : There is a column named "varcharfield" for the "mytable" table but it can not be referenced in this part of the query.

Comment: @GeoGyro This will duplicate the number of rows in that table - is this really what you want?

Comment: You're right, you're answer with an update an not an insert seems to be better.